# Stop the app pool on multiple servers

Tags: c#, iis, application-pool

I have the following function which will stop the app pool on IIS for the machine that the code is hosted on:

```
/// <summary>Stops the application pool.</summary>
/// <param name="appPoolName">Name of the application pool.</param>
public static void StopAppPool(string appPoolName)
{
    ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager();
    ApplicationPool appPool = serverManager.ApplicationPools[appPoolName];

    if (appPool != null)
    {
        if (appPool.State == ObjectState.Started)
        {
            appPool.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is how on earth can I affect the app pool like this for machines where this code is not hosted? i.e. we have two web servers but this code will only be hosted on one of them.

Answer (score 1):

If it is an option, I would use Powershell for this task. In our deployment process we use something like this:

```
function Stop-AppPool {
  param(
    $session = $(throw "session is required"),
    [string]$app_pool = $(throw "app_pool is required")
  )

  Invoke-command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
    param($app_pool)

  Import-Module WebAdministration
    $appPoolPath = "IIS:\AppPools\" + $app_pool
    if (!(Test-Path $appPoolPath -pathType container))
    {
        Write-Warning("The application pool: $app_pool not found. Operation skipped.")
        return
    }

    $state = Get-WebAppPoolState -Name $app_pool
    if ($state.Value -eq 'Stopped')
    {
        Write-Warning("The application pool: $app_pool is already stopped. Operation skipped.")
        return
    }

  Stop-WebAppPool -Name $app_pool

  $retryCount = 0
  Do { Start-Sleep -s 5; $retryCount++; $state = Get-WebAppPoolState -Name $app_pool; Write-Host "$app_pool state.value is $($state.Value)" }
  While (($state.Value -ne 'Stopped') -and ($retryCount -lt 5))

  if ($state.Value -ne 'Stopped') {
      $totalSecs = $retryCount * 5
      Write-Warning "After $totalSecs $app_pool seems to be still runnnig! The actual state.value is $($state.Value)"
    }

  } -ArgumentList @($app_pool)
}
```

where `$session` can be created like this:

```
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $server
```